# Dealing with data loss in kafka connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I understood that Kafka connect can be deployed in cluster mode. And workers move data between data source and kafka topic. What I want to know is if a worker fails when moving data between data source to kafka topic would there be a dataloss? If there would be a dataloss how can we get the data back from the connector or will kafka connect automatically deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the source and if it supports offset tracking.

For example, lines in a file, rows in a database with a primary ID / timestamp, or some idenpotent API call can be repeatedly called and get the same starting position. (although, in each case, the underlying data also needs to be immutable for it to work consistently)

Kafka Connect [SourceTask API has a call to commit](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/source/SourceTask.html#commitRecord-org.apache.kafka.connect.source.SourceRecord-org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.RecordMetadata-) tracked "offsets" (different from Kafka topic offsets)

Comment: so basically even if a broker fails there wont be any data loss right?

Comment: That depends on if the topic has full ISR

Comment: ISR is for kafka topic partitions right? does it exist for kafka connect?

Comment: ISR is for partitions, yes. Kafka Connect maintains its own internal topics, but otherwise acts like any other producer in this case. If the producer was unable to ack the data that is sent, it would be at least duplicated rather than lost because the source offset wouldn't have "moved forward"